# prove Menelaus's theorem by using Ceva's theorem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, projective-geometry

[This article](https://staff.imsa.edu/%7Efogel/ModGeo/PDF/24%20Menelaus%20Ceva.pdf) gives a proof of Ceva's theorem by using Menelaus's theorem twice. However, it also states:

> Oddly, it’s somewhat difficult to go the other way. To prove Menelaus from Ceva requires
> using Ceva six times!

I tried this but didn't get a perfect result:

[image]

(All segments are directed, i.e. $AB=-BA$.)

Apply Ceva onto $\triangle ABE$ and $D$: $$\frac{AF}{FB}\cdot\frac{BG}{GE}\cdot\frac{EC}{CA}=1$$
Apply Ceva onto $\triangle BDE$ and $A$: $$\frac{BC}{CD}\cdot\frac{DF}{FE}\cdot\frac{EG}{GB}=1$$
Apply Ceva onto $\triangle BEF$ and $C$: $$\frac{BH}{HE}\cdot\frac{ED}{DF}\cdot\frac{FA}{AB}=1$$
Apply Ceva onto $\triangle BCE$ and $F$: $$\frac{BD}{DC}\cdot\frac{CA}{AE}\cdot\frac{EH}{HB}=1$$
Apply Ceva onto $\triangle AFC$ and $D$: $$\frac{AB}{BF}\cdot\frac{FJ}{JC}\cdot\frac{CE}{EA}=1$$
Apply Ceva onto $\triangle CFD$ and $A$: $$\frac{CJ}{JF}\cdot\frac{FE}{ED}\cdot\frac{DB}{BC}=1$$

By multiplying these 6 equations, I got: $$\frac{AF^2}{FB^2}\cdot\frac{BD^2}{DC^2}\cdot\frac{CE^2}{EA^2}=1$$

which is very close to Menelaus's theorem but the direction or sign is not determined.

Is there any improvement or I'm in a wrong way?

Comment: Everything becomes simple when you use barycentric coordinates of points (used in your article) vs. barycentric coordinates of lines.